# access to inherited fields in dart

Tags: dart

```dart
abstract class Painter {

    CanvasElement canvas;

    Painter(this.canvas);

    void draw();
}

class SpritePainter extends Painter{

    SpritePainter(this.canvas);

    void draw(){
        window.console.log("Drawing");
        window.console.log(canvas);
    }

}
```

using the above code my application fails when trying to call `new SpritePainter(query('#sprite-canvas'));` saying that `this.canvas` is an unknown field. I thought the `CanvasElement` in the abstract parent class is accessible to the sub class?

**Update:**

I fixed this with:

```
SpritePainter(CanvasElement canvas):super(canvas);
```

but then I read on dart tutorials that abstract classes can only have factory constructors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to forward your param to the super constructor like the following :

```dart
abstract class Painter {
  CanvasElement canvas;

  Painter(this.canvas);

  void draw();
}

class SpritePainter extends Painter{
  SpritePainter(CanvasElement canvas) : super(canvas);

  void draw(){
    window.console.log("Drawing");
    window.console.log(canvas);
  }
}
```